# Why isn't this function returning a value?

Tags: typescript

```js
GetNextdaySchoolMeal():Array<string>{
    fetch(this.GetLink())
      .then((response) => {
        return(response.json());
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return(response.mealServiceDietInfo[1].row[0].DDISH_NM.split("<br/>"));
      })
      .catch(function(error){throw new Error(error);});
  }
```

```
error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

`this.GetLink()` returns the API link for the next weekday. Why can't the `response.mealServiceDietInfo[1].row[0].DDISH_NM.split("<br/>")` in the second `then` callback be returned from `GetNextdaySchoolmeal`?

If I put `console.log` instead of return in the seventh line and delete the type in the first line, it will work as expected. However, I expect that the function returns an array.

Comment: I think its because of you using fetch. I dont know how familiar you are with async/await. But fetch will always return a Promise object. If you want to get that outside the Promise scope , i think just create an empty variable above this function and assign it inside the .then()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to better clarify what ‘Why can't seconds then's return be return’ means (if I've gotten this wrong, please feel free to [edit] your question). Even though I've already answered this question, I've realised that it's the same question as the one linked above — how to work with promises/async APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `fetch` returns a promise. `GetNextdaySchoolMeal` should return `Promise<Array<string>>`.

Once you've fixed that, you need to return the promise. Add a `return` before `fetch`:

```ts
GetNextdaySchoolMeal(): Promise<Array<string>> {
  return fetch(this.GetLink())
    .then((response) => {
      return(response.json());
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return(response.mealServiceDietInfo[1].row[0].DDISH_NM.split("<br/>"));
    })
    .catch(function(error){throw new Error(error);});
}
```

More information on asynchronous functions and promises:

- [‘Introducing asynchronous JavaScript’ on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)
- [‘How to return the response from an asynchronous call’](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/8289918)